# Securing grpc Api calls

Tags: encryption, https, grpc

I want to encrypt data sent in grpc Api calls using our own security classes. I want to encrypt each dto/pojo field. Is there a dynamic way of doing it instead of manually setting encrypted data to each field?
Secondly, can we rely only on Https or encrypting data is good approach?

Comment: Yes, gRPC supports standard TLS encryption or mTLS encryption if you prefer. The implementation of these depends on the language and gRPC clients you plan on using. Can you provide more details about that?

Comment: We are planning to use Java on server side and C# on client side.